# Why does PostUpdateEventListener do not work for @Query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to listen any update of my hibernate entity. I use PostUpdateEventListener to listen updates, and it works fine for all updates when I use standart JpaRepository methods (fetch my entity from DB, update fields and save). But it do  not work when I'm updating record in DB using @Query annotation.

Example:

Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "account")
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
  Long id;

  @Column(name = "description")
  String description;

  @Column(name = "balance")
  BigDecimal balance;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends EntityGraphJpaRepository<Account, Long> {

  @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
  @Query("update account a set "
      + "a.balance = a.balance + :amount "
      + "where a.id = :id")
  int updateBalance(Long id, BigDecimal amount);
}
```

Listener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AccountUpdateListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {

  @Override
  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
    if (event.getEntity() instanceof Account account
        && event.getPersister().getEntityName().equals(Account.class.getName())) {
      //required action
      //reached when repository.save(account)
      //not reached when updateBalance(...) called
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Can some one explain why PostUpdateEventListener do not listen such updates and suggest some solution to listen all updates of my entity?

Comment: Because it is an `EntityListener` and you aren't updating an entity but directly issueing a query. This bypasses the listeners/interceptors....

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, it explains the behavior. But maybe you know another way to implement the same what PostUpdateEventListener provides but for custom queries?

Comment: Database triggers, else update the entity instead of using a query.

Comment: I hoped that there is another way to handle it... But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your post update event to be triggered, your entity must be managed by the persistence context. I suspect that this is not the case in your code. Can you try to update your entity in this way :

```java
@Service
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void updateBalance(Long id, BigDecimal balance) {
        Account account = accountRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException(String.format("No account with id %d", id)));
        account.setBalance(balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, it works in this way, and I mentioned it in the question, but it is not what I'm looking for. Thanks.